# Preventing the Android soft keyboard from moving the view up in a Fragment?

Tags: android, view, keyboard, android-fragments

I have an activity with four tabs and every tab is implemented as a fragment. In one of these tabs I would like to prevent the soft keyboard from pushing up the view, while the keyboard should still push the views up in the other fragments. Does anybody know how to achieve this?

I cannot use the activity's windowSoftInputMode flag, because that would prevent it for the whole activity with all four fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change [flag](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) dynamically

Use the following to change the softInputMode for an Activity in your tab click listener.

`getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);`